# Swift Macros: external macro implementation type could not be found

Tags: ios, azure-pipelines, xcode15, swift-macro, swift5.9

I'm using [MetaCodable](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/MetaCodable) macro in my project, installed via SwiftPM, when I try to build the project using Microsoft Azure's Pipeline using my local machine as a run agent (MBP M1 Max - Sonoma - XCode 15), I get this error message:

`error: external macro implementation type 'CodableMacroPlugin.CodedAt' could not be found for macro 'CodedAt'`

Some folks [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734504) suggest to add `-external-plugin-path` to `other Swift flags` in build settings, but that doesn't solve the issue.

And in [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-import-macros-using-methods-other-than-swiftpm/66645/4) some also suggests to add `-load-plugin-library`, or `-plugin-path`, or `-load-plugin-executable` to `other Swift flags`, I tried every option of these using the value: `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)#MetaCodable` but I got the same error with every CI build.

I also get this warning in the Azure's Pipeline build log:

`"output": "<unknown>:0: warning: compiler plugin not loaded: '/Users/my_user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Release/CodableMacroPlugin; failed to initialize /Users/my_user_name/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.183.1/_work/9/MyProject/Data/Models/SomeModel.swift`

Any thoughts about this are appreciated.

Comment: Are you facing this issue only in CI or when you build your project locally as well? Also, can you provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the issue?

Comment: it's happening on the CI only, local build is working fine. I can't provide an example with Microsoft's Azure CI log here

Comment: Few things you can try: Try building from xcodebuild command line, try some of the solutions suggested on swift forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-allow-trust-the-compiler-plugin-to-run-from-the-command-line/65690, https://forums.swift.org/t/telling-xcode-14-beta-4-to-trust-build-tool-plugins-programatically/59305

Comment: `xcodebuild` command runs without problems on my machine: `xcodebuild -project /Users/xxxxx/MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyScheme -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' build`  but the Microsoft Azure's Pipeline still fails. I even tried to add this command as a CI step (of type Terminal) in Microsoft Azure (in replacement of the original CI build step) but it didn't go through due to the same error

Comment: @neilaur not yet

Comment: I have the same problem, I've not yet found any solution

The real problem is that we cannot use Xcode localization export due to Xcode, and we cannot use xcodebuild due to this problem

It's like a no solution to have both things working..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and after hours found the solution on my side.

For our library we had to define a **macOS support version** besides iOS **for SwiftSyntaxMacros**. Locally we used MacOS 14 and set it to 14.
On the Server we were running 13.X. We did not get a error for the MacOS support version only "error: external macro implementation type 'foo' could not be found for macro 'foo'".

After setting it to **MacOS 12** the issue was gone:

```
platforms: [.macOS(.v12), .iOS(.v15)],
```

I hope this is useful for you. Online I found no solutions for this issue.

Comment: the macro we are using has the `macOS` support, it's added like this: `.macOS(.v10_15)`

Answer (score 3):

If your project works fine in Xcode, but you're seeing this issue only from an `xcodebuild` command or other CI pipeline tool. This can be caused by the `-sdk` flag you've specified (e.g. `-sdk iphonesimulator`).

Simply **REMOVE**:

```
-sdk iphonesimulator
```

From your `xcodebuild` command

Comment: this does not solve the problem